# Bug with MongoClient?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using mongo-java-driver-2.12.4

```java
 import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;
 class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
       MongoClient mc = new MongoClient("hello",27110);
       }catch(UnknownHostException e){
          System.out.println("this is unknown");
       }
       System.out.println("whhaattt");
  }
}
```

Any sane person would say that the output of this code segment should be "this is unknown". It isn't for me for some reason. It is "whhaattt". Why? I am completely stumped.

Edit: So "hello" was resolved on the internal network, but if I put a different value like 1290310923809132 in place of "hello" still no exception is thrown. However the InetAddress.getByName() method does throw an UnknownHostException when ran.

Comment: No that's not right. Under the hood it will call InetAddress.getByName("hello") and I don't see why that wouldn't throw an UnknownHostException.

Comment: I got the exception when I tried it. If you `ping hello`, does "hello" resolve to an IP address?

Comment: So anyway for some reason "hello" resolves on the network i guess it exists in my domain. But if I use some bogus value like "94.doc" in place of "hello" no exception is thrown by the MongoClient. But..... inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("94.doc") does throw an unknownhostexception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this actually is a bug! I submitted it to the MongoDB bug tracker and they said that they changed it starting in 2.12.x versions; however, they did not remove the "throws UnknownHostException" stub. They added a comment to the javadoc stating that the exception is no longer thrown... which means that you can have an invalid MongoClient object. Removing this exception would break source compatibility--> even though binary compatibility would be ok.